# How to show DBMS name and version in laravel view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show a status bar in a laravel website. Which will show the DBMS name and version number. The output I want is like

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.24
```

Or

```
MySQL 5.6
```

I can get the name of database by using `env('DB_CONNECTION')`. It is giving me the name(although, it is showing 'pgsql'; not 'PostgreSQL ').

However, I don't understand how can I get the version number in view. What is the way to get the version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DB::raw() to create database raw expression.

```
 $version = DB::select( DB::raw("select version()"));
```

pass the value to your view.