# How to see pgsql version

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I think multiple pgsql versions are simultaneously running on my system.  I have tried many commands that were shown when i browsed but nothing shown the version. Can anyone help me to know my pgsql version.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is this even related to Laravel?

Comment: @NicoHaase see the updated question, i have added the screenshot of everything that i have tried.

Comment: Please share more details. Either explain how this is related to Laravel, or please remove the irrelevant tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073933/how-to-show-dbms-name-and-version-in-laravel-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one of the following SQL statements:

```
SHOW server_version;
SELECT version();
SELECT current_setting('server_version');
```

You problem is that you don't know how to work `psql`. If you don't terminate a statement with `;`, you get a continuation prompt (note the `-` instead of the `=`).

When in doubt, execute `\r` in `psql`. That will reset the buffer, and you can try again.

Comment: where shall i run this? in sql shell?

Comment: this `SHOW server_version;` worked.Thanks